# Download to folder/files android apps

Tags: java, android, file, ftp, download

my problem is that I use in my practice are pdf files. I did not add them into my application. I want pdf files from ftp or a URL to download it. I have no idea about the solution. I've tried a lot ftp code and URL code. All I want, when you pressed the button of the sdcard files from a URL or FTP address to get a download. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to include as much information as possible to enable users to help you. Generally users assume, you already tried anything in code. Please include that, too. Anything to provide a starting point will help others to help you. At the moment it is hard to decipher what the question is, and what the use case might be.

Comment: thanks for help. i try to add  another information.

Answer (score 2):

this code is working for me

```
   public void onClick(View v) {

        PrintAttributes printAttrs = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
                setColorMode(PrintAttributes.COLOR_MODE_COLOR).
                setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER).
                setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("zooey", PRINT_SERVICE, 300, 300)).
                setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).
                build();
        PdfDocument document = new PrintedPdfDocument(DynamicPDFHelloWorld.this, printAttrs);
        // crate a page description
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(300, 300, 1).create();
        // create a new page from the PageInfo
        PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
        // repaint the user's text into the page
        View content = findViewById(R.id.textarea);

        content.draw(page.getCanvas());
        content.draw(edt.getText().toString().);
        // do final processing of the page
        document.finishPage(page);
        // Here you could add more pages in a longer doc app, but you'd have
        // to handle page-breaking yourself in e.g., write your own word processor...
        // Now write the PDF document to a file; it actually needs to be a file
        // since the Share mechanism can't accept a byte[]. though it can
        // accept a String/CharSequence. Meh.
        try {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/pruebaAppModerator.pdf");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
            document.writeTo(fos);
            document.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error generating file", e);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: i tryed.  but i dont understand this line "content.draw(edt.getText().toString().);" and how i can use to ftp or url link.

Comment: @GOKHAN TEBRIZCIK its edittext and its draw in pdf file